# How to display live camera feed in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getusermedia

## **UPDATE**

I tried modifying the code to use srcObject but somehow it didnt work.

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then( stream => {
            console.log(stream);
            this.streamVideo(stream);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}

streamVideo = (stream) => {
    this.selfVid.srcObject = stream;
};
.
.
.
<video autoPlay className="attendee"/>
<video autoPlay className="selfView" ref={ selfVid => { this.selfVid = selfVid }}/>
```

Not sure if I am doing things correctly.

---

## **Original Question**

I am trying to use webRTC for the first time, so was following some articles but somehow I am not being able to display my camera feed in a video element. With the present code, the camera turns on but throws a TypeError.

**Snippet**

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then( stream => {
            console.log(stream);
            console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
            this.setState({ videoSource: window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.name);
        })
}
.
.
.

<div className="videoWrapper">
    <video autoPlay className="attendee"/>
    <video autoPlay className="selfView" src={ this.state.videoSource }/>
</div>
```

**My Console**

```
Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed.
MediaStream { id: "{78f74e3c-53f5-4aef-93c8-fd5a5a967bb3}", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null }
TypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

I found where I was going wrong.

```
componentDidMount() {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then( stream => {
                console.log(stream);
                this.selfVid.current.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
    .
    .
    .
    <video autoPlay className="selfView" ref={ this.selfVid } />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same thing at the moment, webRTC in reactJS, it's working... here's my code, hopefully helps:

```
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            { video: true, audio: true },
            stream => {
              const localVideo = document.getElementById("local-video");
              if (localVideo) {
                localVideo.srcObject = stream;
              }

              stream.getTracks().forEach(track => this.state.peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

            },
            error => {
              console.warn(error.message);
            }
        );
```

Comment: hey thats great! I will surely give it a try. And it would be great if we could also work together since our motives are same. :)

Comment: Yes that would be great :) maybe you can help me ...I have a 'host' and 'joiner' situation, where people can join a webcam (it's just one way stream)... my problem is that after a connection, the page needs to be refreshed before someone else can connect... otherwise the stream fails, even though socketIO tries to set up the connection. I'm also storing everything in the state, including RTCPeerConnection .. I have no idea is this is a bad way to do it. I can't find much examples of RTC in reactJS ! It ... sorta works though .. lol

Comment: Am also in the same situation of a 'host' and 'joiner', but the fact is I havent been able to reach till that mark. I am currently trying out the 1-1 connection. But I would love to help you on this but again am really a noob at RTC :(

Comment: I'm total noob too :) main problem I ran into was ... needing a STUN server ... it worked over LAN but not over the internet, until added STUN server ... it's easy tho. .. just var servers = { 'iceServers': [{ 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] };  then use: new RTCPeerConnection(servers)  ...

Comment: where are you up to with yours, anyway? ;D

Comment: I just started off today :D :D

Answer (score 0):

URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream) has been deprecated and removed a while ago. Don't rely on outdated documentation.

Set the media elements srcObject property to the stream

Comment: I tried out with refs and srcObject but somehow it didnt workout.

Comment: Ok. Got it working. It was my mistake. Sorry for the trouble.